# how to hide a checkbox inside a datagrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, checkbox, findcontrol

i have datagrid and inside which i have a checkbox . now i want this check to be hidden at page load. my code is :

```
<asp:datagrid id="dgDates" OnItemCommand="gridEventHandler" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px"
CellPadding="3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" AllowSorting="True"
OnSortCommand="SortData" OnItemDataBound="gridItemDataBound">
<HeaderStyle Font-Underline="True" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="Black"
    BackColor="#D4D0C8"></HeaderStyle>
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="strParameterName" SortExpression="strParameterName" HeaderText="Parameter Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="dtParameterValue" SortExpression="dtParameterValue" HeaderText="Parameter Value"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Constant" SortExpression="blnStatic" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbStaticRolling" Checked="False" Runat="server" ></asp:CheckBox>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Are you serious about the formatting of your code example?

Comment: @Ram Try this `CTRL + A` then `(CTRL + K) + F` for formatting code in visual studio and re-edit your question here.

Comment: @Dennis Why did you change it back to being poorly formatted?

Comment: @jadarnel27 I edited it and then it didn't display the code at all, so I rolled back. This probably overlapped with your edit. Sorry.

Comment: @Dennis: Whoops!  No problem, those types of things are inevitable =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the ItemDataBound event

```
public void gridItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
            e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            CheckBox cbStaticRolling= (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("cbStaticRolling");
            cbStaticRolling.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there an ItemDataBound event for the GridView?  [I don't see it in the events on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx#events).  Perhaps you mean [RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)?

Comment: No, for GridView there is not. But the question it's about the old DataGrid

Comment: thanks man! I was writing the answer for RowDataBound originally, but then I figured out that it was about DataGrid =)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbStaticRolling" Checked="False" Visible="False" Runat="server" >
```

Comment: I m using this datagrid to show dyna content for a particular content i dont want to display this check box.